# Configuring FindMe/Hunt Function

Tags: twilio

I have been attempting to configure the FindMe Twimlet with a function so i can possible add more features to this over the basic twimlet. When creating the function and setting the function for the number to use I just get an error when dialing to the number.  Here is what I have, also will this prevent the calls from going to voicemail?

Do I still need to use  TwiML Bin? Or should it work right off this function?

```
 const context = {
  PHONE_NUMBERS: '+1xxxxxx,+1xxxxxx'
};

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const numbers = context.PHONE_NUMBERS.split(',').map(number => number.trim());
  const response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (event.DialCallStatus === 'complete') {
    // Call was answered and completed
    response.hangup();
  } else if (event.finished === 'true') {
    if (context.FINAL_URL) {
      response.redirect(context.FINAL_URL);
    } else {
      response.hangup();
    }
  } else {
    const numberToDial = event.nextNumber ? event.nextNumber : numbers[0];
    const currentNumberIndex = numbers.indexOf(numberToDial);
    let url;
    if (currentNumberIndex + 1 === numbers.length) {
      // No more numbers to call after this.
      url = '/hunt?finished=true';
    } else {
      const nextNumber = numbers[currentNumberIndex + 1];
      url = '/hunt?nextNumber=' + encodeURIComponent(nextNumber);
    }
    const dial = response.dial({ action: url });
    dial.number(numberToDial);
  }
  callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Phil Nash, a Twilio Developer Evangelist, has written a Function to do something similar, you can find a link to the code below.This will not prevent calls from going to voicemail, for that, you would need to implement additional logic, the most reliable being Human Detection discussed here, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-#alternatives-to-amd.

[Hunt / FindMe](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/tree/master/hunt)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue here is that you are trying to set your list of `PHONE_NUMBERS` in the function outside of the handler.

`context` is a parameter that is passed into the handler function by the Twilio Runtime when it is called. It is an object that is populated by the environment variables that are set in the [config area for functions](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure).

I would set your `PHONE_NUMBERS` list as an [environment variable](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure) and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the environment variable did work. I will work with Alans response to sort out the voicemail situation, but one problem I am having with the code is that it does not know here the /hunt URLs go to. So if first call is not answered, the code break. "  url = '/hunt?nextNumber=' + encodeURIComponent(nextNumber);"

Comment: What do you mean the code breaks? I've tested my version of this and it has worked before, so I need a bit more detail.